# Morphisms and Flatness

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Do there exist morphisms $\phi \colon R \longrightarrow S$ of rings such that every $S$-module is flat as an $R$-module?

Comment: It looks like if we assume that if $S$ is flat as an $R$-module, then every flat $S$-module is flat as an $R$-module

Comment: Yes, because for any $S$-module $M$ we have $\otimes_R M\cong (-\otimes_R S)\otimes_S M$.

Comment: Let $S = \{ 0 \}$. Then every $S$-module is flat (even free) as an $R$-module.

Comment: If $R$ is a von Neumann regular ring we get the same thing too.